# Como instalar plataformas SDK no Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

Fiz a instalação do Android Studio e agora preciso baixar e instalar algumas plataformas SDKs para ele. De padrão, ja vem a 7.1.1 instalada, mas preciso instalar todas desde a 4.1, porém, quando clica na caixinha de seleção de cada plataforma, nada acontece, não seleciona. Como proceder?.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Você está tendo esse problema porque o caminho do seu sdk tem um espaço (na pasta Patrick Cardoso) e isso pode causar problemas no NDK.

Mova seu sdk para uma pasta cujo caminho não tenha espaços, como "C:\Android\sdk".

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052934/android-sdk-location-should-not-contain-whitespace-as-this-cause-problems-with

Comment: Essa situação só trás problemas com o uso do [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html) e não no Android Studio em geral. Eu próprio tenho espaços no nome da pasta do SDK e nunca tive qualquer problema.

Comment: @ramaral, mas o próprio aviso ali está falando, acho que deve ser isso mesmo, não?

Comment: @underfilho O aviso fala em relação ao NDK e não ao SDK.